# Using Android Mock Location + Usb Tethering

Tags: geolocation, usb-tethering

I need to have a different location on my Pc , maybe a 5km diffrent , so my question is , if i use some app from the market (example: FakeGPS) and use usb tethering ,  will my Geolocation Ip be on the lat&lon that i set from the app ?